# Why isn't MediaWiki loading?

Tags: linux, mediawiki

I recently set up MediaWiki on an Apache server with PostgreSQL.  It installed successfully.  However, when I try to access the website, I get a blank page.

The error log reports the following.

```
[error] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/mediawiki-1.19.2/LocalSettings.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/mediawiki-1.19.2/includes/WebStart.php on line 134
[error] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/mediawiki-1.19.2/LocalSettings.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/mediawiki-1.19.2/includes/WebStart.php on line 134
[error] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/mediawiki-1.19.2/LocalSettings.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/mediawiki-1.19.2/includes/WebStart.php on line 134
```

I've seen other people with similar problems and the solutions have involved using `chmod` on `LocalSettings.php` to 644 or in other cases 755.  Others have said using `chown` to make `LocalSettings` match the Apache user, which is just 'apache' in my case.  None of these solutions have worked for me.  Does anyone have other suggestions or maybe I missed something?

Comment: Q: Exactly where is your "LocalSettings.php"?  In directory "/var/www/mediawiki-1.19.2"?  Can you "ls -l" to verify this?  PS: Kudos for looking at the error log, and posting the results :)

Comment: Yes, that would be the directory.

Comment: `Permission denied` usually means the file permissions are wrong. Perhaps `apache` is not the name under which PHP runs?

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [sf]

Comment: Are you running on CentOS or some other OS with SELinux enabled? If so, you may need to chcon LocalSettings.php as well.

Comment: I am running CentOS with SELinux enabled.

Comment: I have a test file with phpinfo() showing username/group as apache(48)/48.

Comment: SELinux might be your problem. Have a look at the top of [this article](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/SELinux). I remember I also had issues when installing MediaWiki, but I cannot remember if the error message was the same as yours. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same issue. For me I had just installed an extension into the mediawiki `extensions` folder. The problem was that the folder that my extension resided in (in my case, it was named GraphViz) did not have execute permissions. I fixed it with this:

```
chmod o+x GraphViz/
```

And everything worked again. If that doesn't work, then in the interim you can go into your LocalSettings.ph file and comment out the `require_once` line that is giving you trouble.